# Regex to extract/output quoted strings from a file

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, grep

I wrote a simple regular expression to output quoted strings from a file

```
cat mobydick.txt |  while read line; do echo -n "$line "; done | grep -oP '[^"]*"\K[^"]*'
```

This is what I have so far

For example, when I run this one-liner on this file [mobydick.txt](https://s3.amazonaws.com/itu.ems3.production/attachments/000/214/302/original/mobydick.txt?1428678007) I get the output in a single line instead of new line separated strings.

Could someone help me with my script?

Expected Output --> when the above script is run on mobydick.txt
**"From my twenty-fifth year I date my life."**
**"Call me Ishmael."**

Above input file can be downloaded from this [URL](https://s3.amazonaws.com/itu.ems3.production/attachments/000/214/302/original/mobydick.txt?1428678007)

Comment: post a sample input along with expected output.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Done. Added expected output

Comment: but i have seen many double quoted blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU grep(1) (other incarnations of grep(1) don't have `-P`):

```sh
tr '\n' ' ' <mobydick.txt | grep -P -o '(?<=\s)"[^"]+"(?=\s)'
```

More accurate, using pcregrep(1):

```sh
pcregrep -M -o '(?<=^|\s)"[^"]+"(?=$|\s)' mobydick.txt
```